# Which circuit is better? (Op Amp Question)

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, impedance, photodiode, transimpedance

These circuits are for **sub pA** current detection. Each circuit has the same gain, however; shouldn't the multistage amplifier be theoretically be faster than the single stage gain? TINA TI simulations say they are identical, but I want to know what you guys think. What are the pros/cons of each? Thanks in advance for the help!

[image: Single Stage]

[image: Multi Stage]

Comment: I'm sorry, is that a _1 TΩ_ resistor in that first schematic? That's... impressive. And probably prone to lots and lots of Johnson-Nyquist noise.

Comment: @felthry Yessir! That large value is absurd, however the question I have still holds! :)

Comment: I'd say the second one is better on that alone. Such high-value resistors inject a lot of JN noise into your circuit, and at that resistance, the solder mask on your PCB is of roughly the same order of magnitude in resistance and your circuit becomes incredibly sensitive to dust and especially things like oils from your skin when touching it.

Comment: What is the open-loop gain of that op-amp with the \$1\mathrm{T\Omega}\$ feedback resistor?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri The open loop gain is 120 dB. **Felthry** the current professional technique is to remove the soldermask from the area at which the high gain is occurring. The opamps have guard rings to reduce noise aswell. I've tested the first circuit before; it works, yet the time response is 10s. I want to decrease the time response by using a multistage opamp gain. If I can give you guys something to reference to the **LMP7721 evaluation board** is a great example.

Comment: @felthry ^^ I couldnt tag 2 people in 1 post, but the message about^^

Comment: Oh I understand that there are procedures for using such high impedance things, but if you can avoid having to have such a sensitive component I would recommend it.

Comment: Gotcha, so go for circuit number 2 and see how things turn out?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a dangerous circuit, nor does it seem like an expensive one, so the best thing for it is probably to build it and find out!

Comment: How does Keithley implement their current-measurement machines?

Comment: If the time constant is too long, lower the feedback cap.

Comment: Keithley uses [Integrating ADC's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_ADC) to achieve resolution

Comment: @AlfredCentauri i would love to open one up, but i don't  wanna void the warranty :/

Comment: @felthry unfortunately it is a pretty expensive circuit - with the guarding and components. LMP7721 eval board uses gold traces

Comment: @robert Endl unfortunately, if you lower the feedback cap, the circuit is sensitive yet the noise increases alot

Comment: @laptop2d I think im going to build one of those circuits in the future, I just want to try this way out first! Testing it out with a sourcemeter

Comment: Well, the LMP7721s themselves aren't terribly expensive. Mouser has them for $4.72 each in one-of quantity. It's not the cheapest op amp out there, but it's not something you would worry too much about damaging. But--you probably know more about this than I do! I don't deal with extremely high-precision stuff like this very much.

Comment: thanks for all the help @felthry , your inputs are appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing the opamp types the second circuit will be faster because the RC time constant is massively less in the first stage feedback components. If the second circuit had a 10 nF feedback capacitor then they would be identically fast (again assuming perfect op amps).

> TINA TI simulations say they are identical

Then either you are providing the wrong circuits here or you are doing something wrong in TINA.

Regards noise, the first circuit would be better theoretically because thermal noise from the resistor is not proportional to resistance but the square root. However, you may find that with some opamps, splitting the gain between two stages can overall provide lower noise because of the need to consider the opamp noise gain. Another significant subject.

I would recommend visiting analog devices and using their tool for [photodiode amplifiers](http://www.analog.com/designtools/en/photodiode/). Even if your design isn't a photodiode application, the tool will still be very useful.

You can make it single stage or double stage and play tunes with the values to optimise performance. You can select a vast number of opamp so work with this site and hone the design then try to pick opamp they recommend or find alternatives. I don't think you'll be disappointed.

Comment: I suspect his reference to TINA only deals with DC performance.

Comment: @Andy aka To further specify, identical with respect to the DC Transfer Characteristic. The Opamp I'm using is the LMP7721. My main concern is the time response. Reducing the 1T ohm resistor will dramatically reduce the time response, but I'm curious why I havent seen others use multistage op amps in femtocurrent detection- which is why I posted on the forum. My application is not for photodiodes, but I'll checkout their tool. I appreciate all of the help, thanks!

Comment: Yes the tool is good and there comes a point where the trade offs with noise, noise-gain and bias currents producing unwanted offsets makes a cascaded op-amp better.

Answer (score 2):

This works in simulation, it is going to be difficult to realize this model in the physical world. You'll need an op amp with a lower input bias current than the resistor. The large resistor will add [Jhonson-Nyquist noise](http://web.mit.edu/dvp/Public/noise-paper.pdf), calculate this for a [closed loop opamp](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva043b/slva043b.pdf) and make sure the noise is acceptable with the different resistor combinations.

Another problem that is worth mentioning and you already know about is the problem of other materials (like FR4 of a pcb which has a surface resistivity of 1e7Ω) conducting current into the pin of the op amp. So either dead bug the part, or use guard traces (or you could use a different PCB material with a higher surface resitvitiy ).

> Shouldn't the multistage amplifier be theoretically be faster than the
>   single stage gain?

In this case, yes. The high gain might create bandwidth problems. Graph it out. Draw a horizontal line for the open loop gain of the amplifier, then draw a sloped line with 20db rolloff at unity gain bandwidth point. This is the total gain and bandwidth of your amp. Show below. Now do the same thing for the closed loop gain. Draw a horizontal line for the closed loop gain, and a 20db rolloff line, but this one you need to draw at the frequency cuttoff of the low pass filter point (RC cuttoff point). If the closed loop line doesn't fit within the open loop line, the design won't work as intended.

[image]

> TINA TI simulations say they are identical, but I want to know what
>   you guys think. What are the pros/cons of each?

The first circuit has a larger resistor, larger resistors have larger tolerances which means if your trying to control your filter cuttoff its a larger unknown tolerance.

Since you haven't chosen op amps I cant really comment on what the noise is going to be. The second circuit will have less noise from the resistor, but added noise from a second amplifier.

The [calculated values](http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Thermal-Noise-Calculator.phtml) at a 1Hz cuttoff with and 25C
1TΩ resistor -- 128.286uV-rms
10GΩ resistor -- 12.8286uV-rms

The 1T resistor has a gain of 10^10

The 10G resistor has a gain of 10e8 and the secondary with a gain of 100 for a total gain of 10^10 but now you have the added noise of the second stage op amp that will need to be factored in. The op amp noise of the first will also be multiplied by a gain of 100. You also have voltage offsets of second to worry about.

In my experience if your using the same op amp, it always works out better to do all of the gain in the first stage, however, if you were using two different op amps it might be better to have a second stage.

Comment: I want to make things work with two LMP7721 Op amps- since it's an ultra low noise op amp. And that's exactly what I was worried about- the noise caused by the cascaded stage. What are your thoughts on my opamp selection? I've built the 1st circuit before and the time response is slow (10s) so I'm thinking the multistage may be the best bet to decrease the response time.

Comment: The LMP7721 has a lot of 1/f noise, in fact you may have trouble with that much gain on it. Lets say the noise is 0.1nV/Hz^0.5 (flat, which is a conservative estimate) and you have 10Hz of bandwidth (from 0.01 to 0.1Hz also conservative) that's 1/3uV-rms now multiply that by a gain of 10^10, that's 3.16V-rms of noise. I'm not saying that's what you'll get, but its something to worry about. I would use a rail to rail chopper on the second stage with a low noise, I would definitively try to lower the gain on the first stage.

Comment: hmm, the LMP7721 can definitely take a 10Mohm resistor on the first stage (I've used it on the LMP7721 eval board), however; I need 1E12 total gain. **Should I resort to decreasing the gain to 10E6 on stage one and 1E5 on stage two?** The rail to rail op amp that I currently posses is an OPA350, which has a GBP of 38 MHz and noise of 5 nV/Hz^0.5- but I'm still looking at better solutions! I think your input certainly matches my concern more closely than the others!

Comment: The OPA350 has no information on the 0.1 to 10Hz region which is where most of the noise in an opamp is (and your signal bandwidth is). It also means it is probably not intended for low frequency applications. the 5nv/Hz^0.5 spec only holds for 100Hz and up.

Comment: ah yes, thats right. It looks like i got some smart shopping to do! Thanks for all the help! I'll let you know how things turn out next week!

Comment: Look for choppers, they have no 1/f noise